# Capture session timeout event

Tags: connected-apps, saml, session, logout, identity-provider

We have a requirement, where salesforce is an identity provider for the external system(using SAML). So when a user logouts of salesforce, an external system should be notified. The connected app handles this with 'Single Logout' when the user logouts from UI. However, this does not work on user's session timeout. We have also tried with LogoutEventStream trigger with Force logout on session timeout setting enabled, still we are not able to trigger any event on timeout.

Please do let us know if anyone has came across such a requirement.

Comment: If you tried `LogoutEventStream` with `Force logout on session timeout` setting enabled, it should fire the event. Open a support case with Salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a known issue and is under review.
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001nSIzQAM&title=session-timeouts-do-not-trigger-logouteventstream

Answer (score 1):

As per Salesforce documentation,
LogoutEventStream records logouts, not timeouts. Timeouts don't cause a LogoutEventStream object to be published. If users close their browser during a session, regardless of whether the Force logout on session timeout setting is enabled, a logout event isn't recorded.